# Can I treat the results of a stored procedure like a table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is it possible to do something like this in sql server 2005?

```
WITH tmpTable AS (EXEC spWhatever)
```

Or any other way I can query the data returned from the sp? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE #foo (col1 int, col2 char(10), ...)

INSERT #foo 
EXEC myproc
```

Or loopback (not sure if this still works). Edit: Could be OPENROWSET as per SQLMenace's answer

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (MyServername, 'USE MyDB EXEC myproc')
```

Comment: Temp table worked for what I needed thanks.  Sometimes the answer is right in front of you.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

only with a loopback query if you don't first want to create the table, see here: [Store The Output Of A Stored Procedure In A Table Without Creating A Table](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Store_The_Output_Of_A_Stored_Procedure_In_A_Table_Without_Creating_A_Table)

example

```
      SELECT * INTO #TempSpWho
            FROM OPENROWSET ('SQLOLEDB','Server=(local);TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;',
    'set fmtonly off exec master.dbo.sp_who')

SELECT * FROM #TempSpWho
```

Comment: Yes, you need to enable OPENROWSET first, see here http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-to-enable-xp_cmdshell-on-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 1):

as far as i know you can not. But you can try using User Defined Functions (UDF) instead of SP, if you do that you can you use it like a table.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. I solved my situation by changing the SP to a VIEW.  Now it acts just like a table. That's fine if you don't need to pass any parameters to the SP.

If you do need to pass parameters, make it a table-valued function.